# Handling data on an android app

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a school project and I'm having trouble coming to a conclusion on how to handle the data it involves.

Basically my app lets you create recipes (cooking) that are stored on the phone.

I don't really have any usable code just yet, so far the structure I thought of is as following:

- A class Recipe that represents an individual recipe for manipulation via the app (has all the properties)
- A class RecipeList that has a HashMap with all the Recipe objects in it that lets you get a certain recipe by an Id RecipeList.GetRecipe("id") and save Recipes via RecipeList.SaveRecipe(Recipe), it also handles saving to the SD card

The thing is though that eventually I want to outsource saving to a web space (using PHP) which is part of my project assignment, that's why I decided on using a HashMap so I could utilize an Id.

What's the best way to go about it given my current structure? Or is there a better structure for what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: I read the "Decide if you need a content provider." section on it and none of those seemed to apply to my case.

Comment: That section can be a bit misleading. It's well known that content providers in tandem with a SQLite database is the best way to store large amounts of persistent data.

Comment: To be honest I don't exactly know the difference between MySQL and SQLite but I have never used the latter, is there a possibility of using MySQL as well?

Comment: MySQL is a server based SQL database. SQLite is used for mobile devices. It's a much lighter-weight version of SQL, and it's stored on the device instead of a server. I think you need a bit of reading to do before getting started on this project :) This is a great place to start: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Android-4-Application-Development.productCd-1118199545.html